# jQuery conditionally change events depending on .html( 'string' ) values

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, iteration

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qh8fL/4/

Please feel free to change the heading if you think I've worded it wrong.

**General**

I'm running a wordpress site with multilingual control. And my menu/navigation is dynamic, controlled via the wordpress admin. The multilingual language plugin also changes the dynamic menu/navigation content, as well as page content.

My *Contact* button, which is in the dynamic navigation, opens a sliding menu using jQuery. Very simple animation using top css. The contact button is on the page twice, hence why I'm not using the .toggle for iterations. [See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qh8fL/4/).

**Script**

```
var $button  = $(".contact-button"),
    // var for button which controls sliding div
    $slide   = $("#content-slide");
    // var for the div which slides up and down

$button.on('click', function () {
    // function for when button is clicked

    if ($button.html() == 'Close') {
        // run this if button says 'Close'

        $slide.stop().animate({ top: "-269px" }, 300);
        // close slide animation
        $button.html('Contact');
        // change text back to 'Contact'


    } else {
        // else if button says Contact or anything else

        $slide.stop().animate({ top: "0" }, 300);
        // open slide animation
        $button.html('Close');
        // change text to 'Close'
    }
});
```

**Problem**

Because I'm running multilingual on the site. The navigation spelling changes. [See jsFiddle flag buttons for example](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qh8fL/4/). This is fine, the animation still runs OK, because it's using the button class 'contact-button'.

But because I'm using the .html to replace the text of the button to "Close" and then on the second iteration, back to "Contact" - obviously this is a problem for other languages, as it always changes to English 'close' and back to English 'Contact'

But my three languages and words that I need the iterations to run through are...

Contact - Close
Contatto - Cerca
Contacto - Chiudere

Can anyone help me expand my script to accommodate three languages, all my attempts have failed. The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qh8fL/4/) has the script.

**The language functionality in the fiddle is only for demo purposes, so the iteration sequence can be tested from the beginning. I understand if you change the language whilst the menu is open (in the fiddle), it will confused it. But when the language is changed on my site, the whole page refreshes, which closes the slide and resets the sequence. So it does not matter.**

Any pro help would be awesome thanks!!!

---

**MY POOR ATTEMPT, BUT YOU CAN SEE WHAT I'M TRYING TO ACHIEVE**

```
var $button  = $(".contact-button"),
    // Var for button which controls sliding div
    $slide   = $("#content-slide");
    // Var for the div which slides up and down

$button.on('click', function () {
    // function for when button is clicked

    if ($button.html() == 'Close' || 'Cerca'|| 'Chiudere' ) {
        // run this if button says Close or Cerca or Chiudere

        $slide.stop().animate({ top: "-269px" }, 300);
        // Close slide animation

        $(function () {
            if ($button.html(== 'Close') {
                $button.html('Contact'); }
            else if ($button.html(== 'Cerca') {
                $button.html('Contatto'); }
            else ($button.html(== 'Chiudere') {
                $button.html('Contacto'); }
        });
        // Change text back to Contact in correct language

    } else {
        // else if button says Contact or anything else

        $slide.stop().animate({ top: "0" }, 300);
        // Open slide animation

        $(function () {
            if ($button.html(== 'Contact') {
                $button.html('Close'); }
            else if ($button.html(== 'Contatto') {
                $button.html('Cerca'); }
            else ($button.html(== 'Contacto') {
                $button.html('Chiudere'); }
        });
        // Change text back to Close in the correct language

    }
});
```

See my attempt script above which is not working on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qh8fL/9/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh8fL/2/

When one of the language buttons gets clicked, it stores the strings for Contact and Close using jQuery's `.data()` method. Then, when the contact/close button gets clicked, it refers to those strings rather than having it hard-coded.

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
$("#english").click(function() {
    $(".contact-button").html('Contact').data('langTxt',{contact:'Contact',close:'Close'});
});

$("#spanish").click(function() {
    $(".contact-button").html('Contatto').data('langTxt',{contact:'Contatto',close:'Close'});
});

$("#italian").click(function() {
    $(".contact-button").html('Contacto').data('langTxt',{contact:'Contacto',close:'Close'});
});

if ($button.html() == 'Close') {
    //...
    $button.html($button.data('langTxt').contact);
} else {
    //...
    $button.html($button.data('langTxt').close);
}
```

All you need to do to modify the "close" text appropriately is by editing the `close` property inside the calls to `data()` that occur in each of the click events.

Comment: this won't work because you are still checking for the label 'Close'. You should store a placeholder in your data() instead and set the label and the check condition depending on the generic label. See my coming answer below

Comment: @maxedison thanks your answer on this, this is prob abit to complicated for what I'm after. On my site, I'm not actually controlling the text using the jquery, its all done via my wordpress plugin. I need to run this dependently on the script shown above, the fiddle language script is just for testing. Thanks

Comment: OP -- then you really need to make your question clearer. I'm lost.

Comment: @maxedison - I've update my question to be more specific thanks

Comment: So to be clear, the reason my solution doesn't work is because it sets the text of the button when the user clicks on one of the language buttons. But that doesn't work for you because clicking a language button refreshes the page. Therefore, you need to set the language of the contact button upon initial page load, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should never depend on label strings ... especially in a multilingual environment. Instead you should use placeholders that you store in an attribute (maybe using `.data()`). Then you write your own setters for the labels depending on the value of the attribute.

```
var myLabels = {'close': ['Close', 'Cerca', 'Chiudere'], 'contact' : ['Contact', 'Contatto', 'Contacto']};

var currLang = 2; // to select italian

....

// to set the label
$button.data('mylabel', 'close');
$button.html(myLabels['close'][currLang]);
....

if($button.data('mylabel') == 'close') {
    $button.data('mylabel', 'contact');
    $button.html(myLabels['contact'][currLang]);
} else {
    $button.data('mylabel', 'close');
    $button.html(myLabels['close'][currLang]);
}
```

Comment: I see your method - the current currLang idea will not work because I'm not actually controlling the language via javascript, its all done via the plugin, hence why I'm doing it by string and a class.